# Echo array values in Error Message

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to show the values of the array as part of an error message. But of course when I do the code below I just get my error message with array  at the end. Please help

```
$matches = array("2","35","27");
```

Now I just want to show the values to in a error message.

```
if (isset($matches)){

    $error_message = "The following numbers match: " . $matches;

}

echo $error_message;
```

Result:

```
The following numbers match: 2 35 27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is using [`implode`](http://www.php.net/implode). You may want to do an `is_array` check, but this should work.

```
$error_message = "The following numbers match: " . implode(' ', $matches);
```

Comment: I dont know why I was thinking I had to loop through the values. That was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$matches = array("2","35","27");
if (isset($matches)){
    $error_message = "The following numbers match: " . var_export($matches, true);
}
echo $error_message . "\n";

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The following numbers match: array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => '35',
  2 => '27',
)
```

Look at the [var_export manual here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).